# Passing an environmentObject from an NSHostingController to a SwiftUI view

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a macOS storyboard app in which I am having a SwiftUI view which hosted using an `NSHostingController`. I need to pass an `EnvironmentObject` to this SwiftUI view from my NSHostingController. I am unable to achieve this. I have currently written this code but it does not work. What could be the issue here?

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class SearchText: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}

class HostingController: NSHostingController<SwiftUIView> {


    @objc required dynamic init?(coder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: SwiftUIView().environmentObject(SearchText()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that modifier `.environmentObject` returns different type than you specify in generics, ie `SwiftUIView`.

Here is possible approach

```
class HostingController: NSHostingController<AnyView> {

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: 
            AnyView(SwiftUIView().environmentObject(SearchText())))
    }
}
```

#### Alternate: (Xcode 13.4)

```
class HostingController: NSHostingController<HostingController.HelperView> {
    struct HelperView: View {
       var body: some View {
          SwiftUIView().environmentObject(SearchText())
       }
    }

    @objc required dynamic init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder, rootView: HelperView())
    }
}
```